# Convert WeeklyTrigger.DaysOfWeek to List of (DayOfWeek)

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I am looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
Sunday  = 1
Monday  = 2
Tuesday = 4
Wednesday =8
Thursday = 16
Friday = 32
Saturday= 64
```

This property contains an aggregated value of selected DayOfWeek in the Scheduled Tasks. For example, value 66 is Monday or Sunday.

I would like to convert this value to a List(of DayOfWeek).

What is the best approach to convert values like this?

Comment: To be clear, 66 is `Monday | Saturday`, not `Monday | Sunday`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var weekDays = (int)daysOfWeek;
var weekDayEnumerable = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 7)
    .Where(i => { var isMatch = (weekDays & 1) == 1; weekDays >>= 1; return isMatch; })
    .Select(i => (DayOfWeek)i)
    .ToList();
```

OK, maybe trying too hard to avoid a loop, but you can also convert to a similar for loop if you prefer.

**Update**:

Version that doesn't do any mutation:

```
var weekDays = (int)daysOfWeek;
var weekDayEnumerable = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 7)
    .Where(i => (weekDays & (1 << i)) > 0)
    .Select(i => (DayOfWeek)i)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Time for me to learn more about LINQ! Thanks!

Comment: I was looking at something similar with a property called WhichWeek but couldn not get it to work?

`// WhichWeek.AllWeeks = 31
            // WhichWeek.FirstWeek = 1
            // WhichWeek.SecondWeek = 2
            // WhichWeek.ThirdWweek = 4
            // WhichWeek.FourthWeek = 8
            // WhichWeek.LastWeek = 16
                  var whichWeek = (int)17; // first and last week
            var weeksEnumerable = Enumerable
                .Range(1, 31)
                .Where(i => (whichWeek & (1 << i)) > 0)
                .Select(i => (WhichWeek)i)
                .ToList();`

Comment: The original code converts from a bitfield (`DaysOfWeek`) to an ordinal (`DayOfWeek`). Your new sample code is converting a `WhichWeek` to a `WhichWeek`. I think you want to remove the cast in the `Select` at the end so you end up with a list of `int`.